# Add custom Symfony console commands to Doctrine ORM

Tags: symfony, orm, doctrine-orm

I am working on a simple todos application that runs in the console. The application has only two dependencies:

- "doctrine/orm": "~2.4",
- "symfony/console": "~2.6"

I attempted to see if I can persist my custom 'Task' entity to the database with

`$ vendor/bin/doctrine orm:schema-tool:update --dump-sql` run in the console. The SQL was properly generated - so far so good.

Later, I created my own Symfony console command called `todo:add`. In the bootstrap file, I placed the following code to register the command:

```
$application = new Application('Todos', '0.1.0');
$application->add(new AddTaskCommand($entityManager));
$application->run();
```

The bootstrap file with this code snippet is required by the mandatory `cli-config.php`.

From now on, the only available command displayed by callng `$ vendor/bin/doctrine` is my new custom command and its namespace. All other namespaces and commands that ship with Doctrine ORM are not available.

Consequently, it is not possible to run `$ vendor/bin/doctrine orm:schema-tool:update` anymore.

How can I add my own command without removing other doctrine console commands?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You shouldn't edit anything in the `vendor` directory. `vendor/bin/doctrine` should only have to commands that are coming with the Doctrine packages.

If you want to have custom commands, you should create a new executable file (e.g. `bin/my_app`) with the code that you showed in it. Then you can use `$ bin/my_app todo:add`.

Comment: you're right that one should not change anything in the vendor directory. Please note that I did not modify any code in this directory. Nevertheless, you are right that the solution to the problem was to create a new executable file that loads your custom commands. Secondly, the mandatory `cli-config.php` that is present in the project root directory should not `require` your new executable where you initialize your console application with custom commands. I will, therefore, accept your answer. Thank you.